# java.awt.Color getRed() returns "cannot find symbol"

Tags: java

I'm trying to do this exercise 3.1.6 from the book Introduction to Programming in java by Sedgewick.

```
import java.lang.Object;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.Collections;


public class treetseks{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        List<Color> list;
        list = new ArrayList<Color>();
        Picture pic= new Picture(args[0]);

        int width = pic.width();
        int height = pic.height();

        Picture picr = new Picture(width, height);
        Picture picg = new Picture(width, height);
        Picture picb = new Picture(width, height);

        for (int y = 0; y < height; y++){
            for (int x = 0; x < width; x++){
                Color redpixel = pic.getRed(x, y);
                Color greenpixel = pic.getGreen(x, y);
                Color bluepixel = pic.getBlue(x, y);
                list.add(p);
                picr.set(x, y, redpixel);
                picg.set(x, y, greenpixel);
                picb.set(x, y, bluepixel);
            }
        }

        System.out.println(list);
        pic.show();
        picr.show();
        picg.show();
        picb.show();
    }
}
```

When I try to compile this piece of code I get the compile error message "cannot find symbol" ponting to the getRGB() method. This gives me the idea that I need to import a class or something. But I've already incported java.awt.Color which i think shoud be enough.

The class picture is from this site

http://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/stdlib/Picture.java.html

and is in the same folder as this class.

If I change the getRed() getGreen() getBlue() methods to get() the code works perfect.. I guess it's because i then use the get() method from the class picture instead of the class Color? Am I right? What have I done wrong and how can I use the getRed() getGreen() and getBlue() methods?

Comment: "`getRGB()`" Where is that in your code?

Comment: btw. this is the exercise:Write a program that takes the name of an image file as a command line input, and create and shows three picture objects. One that contains only the red components, one for green and one for blue.

Comment: Check that Java file you've linked to... Where are those methods defined?

Comment: Picture class you linked does not contain "getRed()" method or any other color. I quess your excercise is to provide those methods.

Comment: Sorry.. I changed getRGB to getRed() getGreen() getBlue() and forgot to change it in the question. Same question though and exact same compile error. Just concerning the getRed() getGreen() getBlue().

Comment: Thanks everybody for the very quick and concrete comments and answers. Thanks to you i now have a good idea about what I have to change i the code.. (:

Answer (score 2):

The Picture class you referenced has only method `public Color get(int x, in y);` so change the part:

```
            Color redpixel = pic.getRed(x, y);
            Color greenpixel = pic.getGreen(x, y);
            Color bluepixel = pic.getBlue(x, y);
```

to

```
        Color pixelColor = pic.get(x, y);
        int red = pixelColor.getRed();
        int green = pixelColor.getGreen();
        int blue = pixelColor.getBlue();
        Color redPixel = new Color(red, 0, 0);
        Color greenPixel = new Color(0, green, 0);
        Color bluePixel = new Color(0, 0, blue);
```

So it could be:

```
import java.lang.Object;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.Collections;


public class treetseks{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        List<Color> list;
        list = new ArrayList<Color>();
        Picture pic= new Picture(args[0]);

        int width = pic.width();
        int height = pic.height();

        Picture picr = new Picture(width, height);
        Picture picg = new Picture(width, height);
        Picture picb = new Picture(width, height);

        for (int y = 0; y < height; y++){
            for (int x = 0; x < width; x++){
                Color pixelColor = pic.get(x, y);
                list.add(pixelColor );
                int red = pixelColor.getRed();
                int green = pixelColor.getGreen();
                int blue = pixelColor.getBlue();
                Color redPixel = new Color(red, 0, 0);
                Color greenPixel = new Color(0, green, 0);
                Color bluePixel = new Color(0, 0, blue);

                picr.set(x, y, redPixel);
                picg.set(x, y, greenPixel);
                picb.set(x, y, bluePixel);
            }
        }

        System.out.println(list);
        pic.show();
        picr.show();
        picg.show();
        picb.show();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You do not have methods getRed(),getGreen() or getBlue() in your class. If you want to use those functions you'll have to declare them in your Picture class,otherwise stick to the get() function. To get the individual colors do:

```
Color c = new Color(pic.getRGB());
int redPixel = c.getRed();
int greenPixel = c.getGreen();
int bluePixel = c.getBlue();

picr.set(x, y, new Color(redPixel, 0, 0);
picg.set(x, y, new Color(0, greenPixel, 0));
picb.set(x, y, new Color(0, 0, bluePixel));
```

Answer (score 1):

Your Picture class does not offer getRed(), getGreen(), getBlue() methods.
The only method that i can find that fits your problem is get().

get() returns an instance of the Color class.
Color *does* offer getRed(), getGreen() and getBlue().

So in your code you would do something like

```
Color pixel = picture.get(x, y);
int red = pixel.getRed();
int green = pixel.getGreen();
int blue = pixel.getBlue();

picr.set(x, y, new Color(red, 0, 0));
picg.set(x, y, new Color(0, green, 0));
picb.set(x, y, new Color(0, 0, blue));
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe you meant to use the `getRed()`, etc. methods of the **Color** class. That Picture class doesn't have those methods.

And those methods don't take parameters and instead return ints, not Color objects.

```
final Color rgb = pic.get(x, y);
int redpixel = rgb.getRed();
int greenpixel = rgb.getGreen();
int bluepixel = rgb.getBlue();
```

> If I change the getRed() getGreen() getBlue() methods to get() the code works perfect

It shouldn't work perfect. You've not gotten out the individual colors. When you later use the `picr.set` method, you don't have only red. If you want that, then use the above code, then

```
picr.set(x,y, new Color(redpixel, 0, 0));
```

Then, the others

Answer (score 1):

The method: `Color getRed(int x, int y)`, `Color getGreen(int x, int y)` and `Color getBlue(int x, int y)`, you are trying to use, do not exist.

What does exist, is the method `Color get(int x, int y)` and then you can use the `Color` methods `int getRed()`, `int getGreen()`, `int getBlue()`.

So, you should change part of the for loop to something like this:

```
Color color = pic.get(x, y);
int redPixel = color.getRed();
int greenPixel = color.getGreen();
int bluePixel = color.getBlue();

picr.set(x, y, new Color(redPixel, 0, 0);
picg.set(x, y, new Color(0, greenPixel, 0));
picb.set(x, y, new Color(0, 0, bluePixel));
```

I would also like to note that you could very easily use a class like `BufferedImage` in the future (You do not have to reinvent the wheel).
Finally, according to the [standard naming conventions for Java](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html), the names of the separate color values shoudl be `redPixel`, `greenPixel` and `bluePixel` instead of `redpixel`, `greenpixel` and `bluepixel` respectively.